# Sort array by order of values in other array

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have one array that defines an order,

```
let orderSettingArray = ["Admiral", "Captain", "Lieutenant"]
```

and another array with a few of these values

```
var myArray = ["Lieutenant", "Captain"]
```

I want to sort `myArray` to reflect the order of `orderSettingArray`:

```
var myArraySorted = myArray.getSorted(by: orderSettingArray)
```

Now `print(myArraySorted)` should print `["Captain", "Lieutenant"]`

Comment: Military ranks are one of the ideal use cases for enums. You should take advantage of that.

Comment: @NiravD: You are right (and I should have known about that one :) – This question is a tiny bit more general because it asks for an array extension method, but the underlying ideas are the same. Let's wait for more opinions whether to close this as a duplicate or not.

Comment: @MartinR I know​ that's why I added duplicates question as just suggestion

Comment: The military ranks are just an example. The real scenario has customizable strings. @Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

I've found a better design for this. It has quite a few improvements:

- I use a `Dictionary` to speed up ordering look-ups
- By extracting this behaviour into a separate type, the dictionary can be cached and reused between multiple sorts
- The ordering-derivation is decoupled from sorting, so it could be used in more ways
- The `omitEntirely` responsibility was removed entirely. It should instead by done by a simple call to `filter`, with `hardcodedOrdering.contains` as the predicate.

[***See my new answer, here***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43056896/3141234)

Comment: Wow, such a great exhaustive answer.

Comment: @JOG yeah, it's an operation I've had to do several times, so I've spent quite a some time building and refining this

Answer (score 6):

So Easy  `let new = orderSettingArray.filter{ return myArray.contains($0) }`

Answer (score 2):

- Map each array element to a `(element, index)` tuple, where
  the index is the index of the array element in the order array.
  In your example that would be

  ```
  [("Lieutenant", 2), ("Captain", 1)]
  ```
- Sort the array of tuples by the second tuple element (the index).
  In your case

  ```
  [("Captain", 1), ("Lieutenant", 2)]
  ```
- Extract the array elements from the sorted tuples array.
  In your case

  ```
  ["Captain", "Lieutenant"]
  ```

Code (for any array of equatable elements, not restricted to arrays of strings):

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func getSorted(by orderArray: [Element]) -> [Element] {

        return self.map { ($0, orderArray.index(of: $0) ?? Int.max) }
            .sorted(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 })
            .map { $0.0 }

    }
}

let orderSettingArray = ["Admiral", "Captain", "Lieutenant"]
let myArray = ["Lieutenant", "Captain"]
let myArraySorted = myArray.getSorted(by: orderSettingArray)
print(myArraySorted) // ["Captain", "Lieutenant"]
```

Elements in `myArray` which are not present in `orderSettingArray`
are assigned the index `Int.max` and therefore sorted to the end
of the result.

Comment: Hello, Don't you think that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44017405/5501940) is even simpler? and it should be applicable for any array of equatable elements, not restricted to arrays of strings...

Comment: @AhmadF: The difference is that it won't handle repeated elements in `myArray`, or elements in `myArray` which are not in `orderSettingArray`. If that is not an issue, the solution is fine.

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 3

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func getSorted(by: Array<String>) -> Array<String> {
        var d = Dictionary<Int, String>()

        for value in self {
            for i in 0 ..< by.count {
                if value as! String == by[i] {
                    d[i] = value as? String
                }
            }
        }

        var sortedValues = Array<String>()
        for key in d.keys.sorted(by: <) {
            sortedValues.append(d[key]!)
        }

        return sortedValues
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is only functional for `[String]`

Comment: Oh boy, this is unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Not optimal, sure. Complex, nah. :)