# Swift sorting four different type object with same property in array (AnyObject)

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

```
class ComparedObject {
    let id: String
    let order: Int
    ...
}

class Object1 {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    ...
}

class Object2 {
    let id: String
    let x: Float
    ...
}

class Object3 {
    let id: String
    let y: Int
    ...
}

class Object4 {
    let id: String
    let z: Double
    ...
}

var comparedList: [ComparedObject] = [ComparedObject, ComparedObject, ComparedObject, ComparedObject]

var list = [AnyObject] = [Object2, Object1, Object3, Object4]
```

I have four classes, all with id: String attribute.

And I want to store them into one (AnyObject) array to show in UICollectionView.

So how can I sort list array with comparedList id attributes?

comparedList is already sorted.

I want sort list array from comparedList id attribute:

```
var comparedList = [
    ComparedObject(id: "01d7da417657", order: 0),
    ComparedObject(id: "61a96d769843", order: 1),
    ComparedObject(id: "5047abd36432", order: 2),
    ComparedObject(id: "3213f37a4003", order: 3)
]

var list = [
    Object2(id: "3213f37a4003", x: 34.0),
    Object1(id: "61a96d769843", name: "name"),
    Object3(id: "01d7da417657", y: 9),
    Object4(id: "5047abd36432", z: 0.3)
]
```

To this:

```
var list = [
    Object3(id: "01d7da417657", y: 9),
    Object1(id: "61a96d769843", name: "name"),
    Object4(id: "5047abd36432", z: 0.3),
    Object2(id: "3213f37a4003", x: 34.0)
]
```

**Finally I did it like this:**

```
comparedList = comparedList.sorted { $0.order < $1.order }
var comparedOrder = comparedList.map { $0.id }

list.sort { (comparedOrder.firstIndex(of: $0.id)! < comparedOrder.firstIndex(of: $1.id)! }
```

Comment: It can be done, but what about using a Protocol to define that? Did you try something?

Comment: Sorry for that I updated my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting a Swift array by ordering from another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056807/sorting-a-swift-array-by-ordering-from-another-array). Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44017101/sort-array-by-order-of-values-in-other-array

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a `protocol` that defines a requirement for an `id: String` property, then make all your types conform to said protocol and instead of storing them as `AnyObject`, store them as the protocol type. This will enable you to sort the array based on `id`.

```
protocol MyIdentifiable {
    var id: String { get }
}

struct ComparedObject: MyIdentifiable {
    let id: String
}

struct Object1: MyIdentifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}

struct Object2: MyIdentifiable {
    let id: String
    let x: Float
}

struct Object3: MyIdentifiable {
    let id: String
    let y: Int
}

struct Object4: MyIdentifiable {
    let id: String
    let z: Double
}

let comparedList = [ComparedObject(id: "!")]
let list: [MyIdentifiable] = [Object1(id: "1", name: "1"), Object2(id: "2", x: 2.0)]
let sortedList = list.sorted(by: { $0.id < $1.id })
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I want to sort list array from comparedList array id attribute.

Comment: @hichkas that's a completely different question from the original. If your actual issue isn't how to store different types with some common properties in a single array and sort them based on said common properties, but the problem is how to sort an array based on the order of another array, then the question is a duplicate of [Sorting a Swift Array by ordering from another Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056807/sorting-a-swift-array-by-ordering-from-another-array/43056896#43056896)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I figured it out how to sort.