# Sort an object array [Venue] by its property using a sorted array [Geofire Keys] as reference?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, object, geofire

I have built the following "helper" function, which takes as parameters:

- '**unsortedArray**': The array of Venue objects required to be sorted by its .venueID string property
- '**sortingGeoArray**': the Geofire string keys to be used as reference to order the unsorted array above.

and it returns a sorted array of type [**Venue**] via an escaping handler.

I have tried to implement this nice and simple solution suggested on the following thread:

'[Sorting a Swift array by ordering from another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056807/sorting-a-swift-array-by-ordering-from-another-array)'

```
    func sortVenuesArraybyGeofireKeys(unsortedArray: [Venue], sortingGeoArray: [String] , handler: @escaping (_ sortedArray: [Venue]) -> ()){

    let ordering = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: sortingGeoArray.enumerated().map { ($1, $0) })
    let sorted: [Venue] = unsortedArray.sorted{ ordering[$0.venueID]! < ordering[$1.venueID]! }

    handler(sorted)

}
```

I have tried the sorting code above in multiple places through out my code by I always get a **"Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"** at the following line (works when i test it an playground):

```
let sorted: [Venue] = unsortedArray.sorted{ ordering[$0.venueID]! < ordering[$1.venueID]!
```

On my debug window below, I have a feeling that the .map function into the let '**ordering**' is not working and therefore finding nil on the next line

any help would be appreciated.

[image]

**UPDATE**: thanks to the support below, it appears that my Geofire query below in particular the 'append' to venueGeoKeys [string] array is not appending the key values, hence why found nil when I execute the function to sort.

```
        let query = self.GEOFIRE_VENUES.query(at: location, withRadius: 1000)
    query.observe(.keyEntered) { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in

        self.venueGeoKeys.append(key)
    }
```

Comment: Your code will only work if every venueId found in `unsortedArray` exists in the `sortingGeoArray` array. Your code is crashing because this isn't true when you run your code.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in this direction. the following code is not appending the geoReference to the arrary which is then passed to the function above. I printed the count to the console and it returns 0       let query = self.GEOFIRE_VENUES.query(at: location, withRadius: 1000)
        query.observe(.keyEntered) { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
            self.venueGeoKeys.append(key)
        }

Comment: @rmaddy I have updated my question above.

Comment: You need to show all of this code in context. Show when and where you call this query and when and where you call your `sortVenuesArraybyGeofireKeys` method.