# Sort an array A in Swift based on (1) an incomplete array B and (2) alphabetically

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array `tags` which include several elements with `id` and `name`. I also have an array `order` where *some* of the elements in `tags` are present. Here is what I want to achieve:

1. All elements in `tags` should be sorted according to `order`.
2. Those elements which is not present in `order` should be ordered alphabetically after the elements which are present in `order`.

I have solved it using a `for` loop (the code runs in Playground):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct Tag: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

// Ccc > Bbb > Aaa > Ddd > Eee
var tags = [Tag(id: 1000, name: "Ccc"), Tag(id: 1001, name: "Bbb"), Tag(id: 1002, name: "Aaa"), Tag(id: 1003, name: "Ddd"), Tag(id: 1004, name: "Eee")]

// Eee > Ddd > Ccc > Bbb > Aaa
tags.sort(by: { $0.name < $1.name })

// Bbb > Ddd
var idOrdering = [1001, 1003]

// Bbb > Ddd > Aaa > Ccc > Eee
for orderIndex in idOrdering.indices {
    // Get tag id.
    let tagId = idOrdering[orderIndex]

    let tagIndex = tags.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == tagId })

    // Remove tag from original array and place it according to the `order`.
    let removedTag = tags.remove(at: tagIndex!)
    tags.insert(removedTag, at: orderIndex)
}

// Print the result.
tags.forEach {
    print($0.name)
}
```

The order of the elements in the original `tags` is `Ccc > Bbb > Aaa > Ddd > Eee`. Two of the elements named `Bbb` and `Ddd` should be ordered based on `order`, that is, `Bbb > Ddd`. The rest should be ordered alphabetically. In other words, the end result should be `Bbb > Ddd > Aaa > Ccc > Eee`. Although the `for` loop above works, how can I solve this problem more efficiently?

Comment: Seems like this answer of mine is an exact match for what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43056896/3141234

Comment: The `UUID`s in this question are unwieldy and distract from the core problem. I recommend you replace them with small `Int`s, and produce an expected `output` array.

Comment: `x = x.sorted { ... }` is a bad practice. Either just use the in-place variant (`x.sort { ... }`), or better yet, just create a new variable.

Comment: Code updated according to feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603960/swift-sort-array-of-objects-with-multiple-criteria/37612765#37612765) mentioned by [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61417552/2906284) I ended up with the following solution:

```
tags.sort {
    (idOrdering.firstIndex(of: $0.id) ?? idOrdering.count, $0.name) <
    (idOrdering.firstIndex(of: $1.id) ?? idOrdering.count, $1.name)
}
```

Comment: Why `idOrdering.count + 1`?

Comment: I would have use a constant: `Int.max` instead.

Comment: How and why do you want to use a constant?

Answer (score 0):

I would combine two bits of code:

1. `HardCodedOrdering` from [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43056896/3141234), which uses a fixed-ordering (such as your `order` array) to derive sort keys for objects.
2. Use this pattern to sort an object according to multiple criteria: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37612765/3141234

```
import Foundation

struct Tag: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

// Bbb > Ddd
let idOrdering = HardCodedOrdering(ordering:
    UUID(uuidString: "007D8DD7-7DF7-4937-BE53-C8CCE9C34A09")!,
    UUID(uuidString: "B1792EF4-CD4C-4437-90C2-37FE56D3A18F")!,
    sortUnspecifiedItems: .last
)

// Ccc > Bbb > Aaa > Ddd > Eee
let tags = [
    Tag(id: UUID(uuidString: "20FCD62B-97B8-4097-B659-29357EABE786")!, name: "Ccc"),
    Tag(id: UUID(uuidString: "007D8DD7-7DF7-4937-BE53-C8CCE9C34A09")!, name: "Bbb"),
    Tag(id: UUID(uuidString: "36FCEBF2-9912-4D67-A0F3-5EE1BF6EFE86")!, name: "Aaa"),
    Tag(id: UUID(uuidString: "B1792EF4-CD4C-4437-90C2-37FE56D3A18F")!, name: "Ddd"),
    Tag(id: UUID(uuidString: "463927D5-F6D8-4099-99FC-D3DE226B00C9")!, name: "Eee"),
]

let result = tags.sorted {
    (idOrdering.sortKey(for: $0.id), $0.name) <
    (idOrdering.sortKey(for: $1.id), $1.name)
}

result.forEach { print($0) }
```

Comment: Is your `HardCodedOrdering()` more efficient than my `for` loop above?

Comment: @Simen Theoretically, it has better asymptotic time complexity, but obviously you have to profile it to be sure. But frankly, it doesn't even matter how efficient it is, it's actually understandable, which is *way* more important.