# Can I sort an enum's cases by order of declaration?

Tags: swift

In Swift, when an `enum` conforms to `CaseIterable`, ["The synthesized allCases collection provides the cases in order of their declaration."](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable)

I would like to sort an array of `CaseIterable` enum cases, which means conforming to `Comparable`. Can I access this same order of declaration to determine how such objects should be sorted?

If not, is my implementation of `<` below reasonable?

```
enum MyEnum: CaseIterable, Comparable {
    case one, two, three
}

static func < (lhs: MyEnum, rhs: MyEnum) -> Bool {
    guard let lhsIndex = allCases.firstIndex(of: lhs), let rhsIndex = allCases.firstIndex(of: rhs) else {
        fatalError("`MyEnum`'s implementation of `Comparable.<` found a case that isn't present in `allCases`.")
    }
    return lhsIndex < rhsIndex
}
```

Finally, is it possible to go one step further and make `CaseIterable` itself conform to `Comparable` this way? Any reason this would be a bad idea?

Comment: I have a generalized solution for this problem, which I outline here: HardCodedOrdering https://stackoverflow.com/a/43056896/3141234

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Swift 5.3 and later you can use the synthesized conformance to `Comparable` for any enum that either has no associated value or has an associated value that conforms to `Comparable`.

For example:

```
enum Size: Comparable {
    case small
    case medium
    case large
    case extraLarge
}

let shirtSize = Size.small
let personSize = Size.large

if shirtSize < personSize {
    print("That shirt is too small")
}
```

I have an article providing information on this change, along with other features introduced in Swift 5.3: [What’s new in Swift 5.3?](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/218/whats-new-in-swift-5-3)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to make your `enum` conform to `RawRepresentable` with an `Int` `RawValue` type, like the other answers here have posted, then your approach seems reasonable to me.

As for this question:

> Finally, is it possible to go one step further and make `CaseIterable` itself conform to `Comparable` this way?

Yes, you could make an extension on `Comparable` that contains a default implementation of the `<` function and constrain the extension to only apply when `Self` also conforms to `CaseIterable`, as shown below:

```
extension Comparable where Self: CaseIterable {
    static func < (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        guard let lhsIndex = allCases.firstIndex(of: lhs), let rhsIndex = allCases.firstIndex(of: rhs) else {
            fatalError("`\(Self.self)`'s implementation of `Comparable.<` found a case that isn't present in `allCases`.")
        }
        return lhsIndex < rhsIndex
    }
}
```

This will give this `<` function to any enum you declare as conforming to both `Comparable` and `CaseIterable`.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the enum accessed in the same order as the declaration by providing an `Int` raw type to your enum:

```
enum MyEnum: Int, CaseIterable {
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a pretty good solution (given the garbage constraint we have that `<` isn't allowed to throw ). You can reuse pieces though and not have to create an error message especially for `<`.

```swift
public extension Result {
  /// `success` for `Optional.some`s; `failure` for `.none`s.
  init(
    success: Success?,
    failure getFailure: @autoclosure () -> Failure
  ) {
    self =
      success.map(Self.success)
      ?? .failure( getFailure() )
  }
}
```

```swift
/// A type with a `comparable` property, used for `<`.
public protocol comparable: Comparable {
  associatedtype Comparable: Swift.Comparable
  var comparable: Comparable { get }
}

public extension comparable {
  static func < (comparable0: Self, comparable1: Self) -> Bool {
    comparable0.comparable < comparable1.comparable
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable {
  /// The first match for this case in `allCases.indices`.
  /// - Throws: `AnyCaseIterable.AllCasesError.noIndex`
  func getCaseIndex() throws -> AllCases.Index {
    try Result(
      success: Self.allCases.firstIndex(of: self),
      failure: AnyCaseIterable.AllCasesError.noIndex(self)
    ).get()
  }
}

public enum AnyCaseIterable {
  public enum AllCasesError<Case>: Error {
    /// No `AllCases.Index` corresponds to this case.
    case noIndex(Case)
  }
}

public extension comparable where Self: CaseIterable {
  /// The index of this case in `allCases`.
  var comparable: AllCases.Index { try! getCaseIndex() }
}
```

```swift
enum MyEnum: CaseIterable, comparable {
  case one, two, three
}

MyEnum.one < .three // true
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, you can use simpler approach.

```
enum MyEnum: Int, CaseIterable, Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: MyEnum, rhs: MyEnum) -> Bool {
        lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
    }

    case one, two, three
}
```

Regarding your second question, I don't think it is even possible to implement the `Comparable` protocol for the `CaseIterable` protocol.