# SwiftData ordered many-to-many relationship

Tags: swift, swift-data, swift-data-relationship

How to have `Watchlist.movies` be ordered like whatever array I assign? I cannot add an order property to `Movie` because it can appear in multiple `Watchlist`s.

```swift
@Model
final class Watchlist {
    var movies = [Movie]()
    
    init() {}
}

@Model
final class Movie {
    @Relationship(inverse: \Watchlist.movies)
    var watchlists = [Watchlist]()
    
    init() {}
}
```

Not a duplicate of [SwiftData IOS 17 Array in random order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76889986/swiftdata-ios-17-array-in-random-order) because that deals with the "why" and doesn't address many-to-many relationships.

### Considered solutions

This seems a like a hack and requires saving because `PersistentIdentifier` is temporary until the first save:

```swift
@Model
final class Watchlist {
    var movies: [Movie] {
        get {
            moviesOrder.compactMap{ modelContext?.model(for: $0) as? Movie }
        }
        set {
            moviesOrder = newValue.map{ $0.persistentModelID }
        }
    }
    private var moviesOrder = [PersistentIdentifier]()
    
    init() {}
}
```

But it's simpler than creating a separate MovieResult model with an order property and sorting on every get. Which is what the [OrderedRelationship lib](https://github.com/FiveSheepCo/OrderedRelationship) seems to do.

Comment: If you need to persist the order which I assume you want then you could add a third model that sits in between the two you have, WatchListItem, with an order and Movie property. Or you could have an order property on WatchList that is an array of Movie.ID, this would mean one less model but it might a lot of work managing this property and maybe also to use it in an efficient way.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That's what the linked library does (as a macro). It requires an extra model and sorting on every get though. How do you think that stacks up against the other solution in the question?

Comment: Well with that solution you won't have a relationship at all between the models, could that be an issue? If you delete a Movie then you must go through all Watchlist objects and remove its id from movieOrders.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have posted the intermediary model solution for comparison but I'm hoping for something better than either of these solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution with an intermediary model. It seems like the best type of solution so far but I don't like it much because it requires an additional model and sort on every `get`.

```swift
@Model
final class Watchlist {
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \WatchlistMovie.watchlist)
    private var moviesUnordered = [WatchlistMovie]()
    
    var movies: [Movie] {
        get {
            moviesUnordered
                .sorted(using: SortDescriptor(\.order))
                .map{ $0.movie }
        }
        set {
            moviesUnordered.forEach{ modelContext!.delete($0) }
            moviesUnordered = newValue.enumerated().map{ offset, movie in
                WatchlistMovie(self, movie, order: offset)
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {}
}

/// An intermediary between `Watchlist` and `Movie` used to retain insertion
/// order.
@Model
final class WatchlistMovie {
    var watchlist: Watchlist!
    var movie: Movie!
    let order: Int
    
    init(_ watchlist: Watchlist, _ movie: Movie, order: Int) {
        self.order = order
        
        watchlist.modelContext!.insert(self)
        self.movie = movie
        self.watchlist = watchlist
    }
}


@Model
final class Movie {
    let name: String
    @Relationship(inverse: \WatchlistMovie.movie)
    var watchlistItems = [WatchlistMovie]()
    
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```